# Probability of intersection given condition

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Why are the following relations true , how to derive this ?

```
p(a,b|c) = p(a|b,c).p(b|c)

p(a,b|c) = p(b|a,c).p(a|c)
```

Comment: Write out the definition...

Comment: @QiZhu Can you please explain what you mean by that ?

Comment: I'm not sure what needs to be explained. Really just plug in the definition and you're done... (Besides on this forum you should show some of your own attempts.)

Comment: Remember that $\mathbb{P}(A|B,C)$ really means $\mathbb{P}(A|B \cap C)$ (at least if $A,B$ and $C$ are three events). Can you try the computation now?